# bulk load to azure using php

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, sqlsrv

I am trying to load CSV to an Azure webserver database using PHP. The CSV's are 2000 lines each. I have it working but when I run the file on the web page the database is only updated with 479 entries and I am not sure why. The webpage takes a long time to process then it will show the page saying its completed. Here's what I have for the insert statement.

```
try {
    $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:".$SrvName.",1433; Database = ".$DBName, $SQL_USER, $SQL_PASS);
    if (($handle = fopen("personal.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO personal (clientId, lastname, ssn)
                    VALUES ($data[0], $data[1],$data[2])";
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
```

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: Web pages often have a maximum upload size - have you checked that.

Comment: Inserting data RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) is, as the acronym suggests, agonizing. You have the .csv file already spooled to disk on the PHP server, so why not use the purpose-made [bcp.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) to perform the bulk insert in a single operation?

Comment: We also can use **BULK INSERT** to insert data into the Azure sql table from the csv file s locally and in Azure. As stated in this [post](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-bulk-insert-import-data-locally-azure/).

Comment: Have not tried the actual bulk insert, will that actually work going to the azure web app?

Comment: @John Iacoucci  I think it can be achieved in theory.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try as well as bcp suggested by always learning

Comment: @JosephXu I tried the bulk insert and it would work if I was just having to use the query editor in Azure, but I am having to do it in PHP and upload the files to the web app server where they will execute. Since I have to do it that way I cannot use the bulk insert inside of PHP sadly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am trying to figure out how to use BCP in PHP, I have seen where it is used in the cmd but I have not found much of anything on how to use it within PHP. Any insight into this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we have two solutions:

**Solution1**
[How to: Send Data as a Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/sql/connect/php/how-to-send-data-as-a-stream?view=sql-server-2016): The Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server takes advantage of PHP streams for sending large objects to the server.

**Solution2**
Design a stored procedure, pass the file name as a parameter.
Example code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBulkInsert]  @FileName varchar(255)
AS
declare @sql varchar(max)
BEGIN Try
set @sql =  
'INSERT into  ext.customer_Staging with (TABLOCK) (customer, age, gender)
   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK '+ @FileName + ',
   DATA_SOURCE = ''MyDataSource'',
   FORMAT = ''CSV'',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = ''MyDataSource''
   ) AS DataFile;
   go'

 exec(@sql)
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

GO
```

Then use php to call this sqlserver stored procedure instance.

---

But don't **BULK INSERT** into your real tables directly.

- I would always insert into a staging table ext.customer_Staging (without the IDENTITY column) from the CSV file
- possibly edit / clean up / manipulate your imported data
- and then copy the data across to the real table with a T-SQL statement like:

```sql
INSERT into  ext.customer_Staging with (TABLOCK) (customer, age, gender)
   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'bs140513_032310-demo.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyDataSource',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyDataSource'
   ) AS DataFile;
   go

INSERT INTO ext.customer(Name, Address) 
   SELECT customer, age, gender
   FROM ext.customer_Staging
```